# Subbasis for the Prodiscrete Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be a sets and let $A^B$ be the product of $\prod_{b\in B}A$, so the set of all mappings $f:B\rightarrow A$. Equip each factor of $A^B$ with the discrete topology and the product $A^B$ with the product topology. We know that the subbasis for the product topology on $A^G$ is the union of the collection of sets $\mathcal{S}=\cup_{\beta\in B} S_\beta$ where $S_\beta=\{\pi_\beta^{-1}(U)\mid U \text{ is open in}  A\}$ and $\pi_\beta^{-1}(U)$ is the inverse image  of the set $U$ under the canonical projection $\pi_\beta^{-1}$.

The claim that I came across was that the elementary cylinders $C(\beta,\{a\})=\pi_\beta^{-1}(a)=\{f\in A^B\mid f(\beta)=a\}$ form a subbasis for the product topology. To check that this is a subbasis, we need to check that the union of all of the elementary cylinders covers $A^B$. This is where I am having an issue; if we fix a $\beta\in B$, the the union $\cup_{a\in A}C(\beta,\{a\})$ consists of all mappings $f: B\rightarrow A$ such that $f(\beta)=a$ as $a$ runs over all of $A$. Wouldn't this just be the set of all mappings in $A^B$? If this were the case, then the collection of cylinders of the form $C(\beta,\{a\})$ for a fixed $\beta$ and for all $a\in A$ would be a subbasis, but I don't think it would be a subbasis for the product topology. Am I missing something or is this just a subbasis for another topology?